# Getting known registration by name in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, simple-injector, mediator

I am trying to get hold of an instance of a Mediator Request, I thought that using IoC could be viable.

Given the following registrations:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRequest<>), assemblies);
container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), assemblies);
```

And the following class

```
public class SubtractRequest: IRequest<int>
{
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Right{ get; set; }

    public SubtractRequest() { }

    internal class Handler : IRequestHandler<SubtractRequest, int>
    {
        public Handler() {}

        public string Handle(SubtractRequest request)
        {
            return request.Left - request.Right;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to resolve an instance by name `"SubtractRequest"`.

My intention is to take a JSON-RPC object, something like this: `{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "subtract", "params": [42, 23], "id": 1}`, extract the method and then get an instance of that mediator request by that method name.

```
var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonRpcRequest>(jsonRpcRequest);
var mediatorRequest = GetRequestByName($"{request.Method}Request"); //Via IoC?
//SetParams(mediatorRequest) [todo]
var result = mediator.Send(mediatorRequest).Result;
```

Basically I am trying to work out how best to implement my GetRequestByName() method to get the correct mediator request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very broad question and the answer depends on the framework you are using and how this data is coming in, but in general, you will have to:

- relate the incoming request to a specific `IRequest<TResponse>` message.
- extract the `TResponse` type from that request message type.
- deserialize the incoming request to the request type.
- create a closed-generic `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>` version based on the request type and the `TResponse` type.
- resolve that closed `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>` from the `Container`.
- Call the handler's `Handle` method.

There is a Reference Architecture application on Github called [SOLID Services](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices) that contains examples on how to do this. Especially take a look at the [QueryDelegatingHandler](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices/blob/master/src/WebApiService/Code/QueryDelegatingHandler.cs) implementation in the Web API project, since it basically does what you need. You might want to download the complete project and play around with it, but do note that the interfaces are named a bit differently. Where you call things `IRequest<TResponse>` and `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>`, the sample project calls this `IQuery<TResult>` and `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>`. The idea however is the same.

One last note, please remove the following registration:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRequest<>), assemblies);
```

`IRequest<TResponse>` is the definition for a message. A message is a DTO and creating them is not a concern of your DI Container. Registering them into your container might prevent you from succesfully verifying the container's configuration. The only thing you should register is `IRequestHandler<,>`.

**UPDATE**:

This is basically how your code should look:

```
Type requestType = GetRequestTypeByName($"{request.Method}Request");

dynamic request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestType, jsonRpcRequest);

object result = ((dynamic)mediator).Send(request).Result;
```

You will have to implement `GetRequestTypeByName`. This is *not* something that your DI Container can help you with. Just go over the types in the assembly using reflection and find the type named `{request.Method}Request`.

Comment: Many thanks for the response, I don't think I explained why I wanted to do what I am doing. I have added additional information to my question but fear I have made this excellent answer irrelevant.

Comment: I am using a mediation library (Mediatr) to get and handle all the requests when I call `mediator.Send(...)` and this is all working fine with the IoC (I have tested this by newing up a SubtractRequest, sending it, and getting the correct result). My problem is, rather than newing it up myself, I want to take a string name, find and create a `{name}Request` via this name and send it on to allow the handler to do it's thing. I think I am likely trying to do something very silly with IoC where simple reflection should be used. Sorry for the confusion but thanks for the help.

Comment: My answer stays the same. You will have to deserialize the incoming data to the proper request and pass it on to MediatR. This has little to so with your DI Container, it's just reflection you'll have to do.